# How to add a Component Type of "Plug-in Type" to a Solution Manually

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

When adding "SDK Message Processing Steps" to a solution in CRM 2016.2, the standard Missing Required Components shows up, with fields that are in my Plugin Steps, but then it also shows the actual plugin type itself (i.e. the class):
[image]

I don't see any way to add a Plugin-Type (the Plugin Assembly yes, the Steps yes, but not the type) to the solution manually.  This requires me to say yes to include all required components, and then remove the fields that already exist.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think it is indeed prompting about the "Plugin Assembly" which holds the plugin class. I don't think there is a component type of "Plugin-Type".

Comment: I already have the plugin assembly added, and the name listed is the plugin class name, not assembly name...

Comment: Anything interesting if you scroll right?

Comment: Just lists Managed Solution as "Active Solution" and Dependency Type as "Published".  Looks like even if I have already previously added the Type as part of another step it wants to add it..

Comment: Interesting, looks like there is an "entity" called "PluginType", just not available to access/add using the UI. Searching early bound Xrm.cs yielded --> `public partial class PluginType : Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntity`

Comment: Has the type been renamed during development but kept within the same assembly?  I'd be interested to see the difference in the exported solution XML when selecting Yes and No.

Comment: [Plug-in Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327902.aspx) `A plug-in type identifies the object type that a plug-in assembly contains. This type can be either a plug-in or a custom workflow activity. A plug-in type statistics stores information about the run-time behavior of a plug-in type and other statistical information.` - So there is an entity by the name "Plug-in Type" just not accessible from the UI.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm thinking this is a bug in the Require Components logic of CRM.  Sounds like that should be included in the Assembly itself....

Comment: What i use to do is add the plugin type through add required components. Having this issue in CRM online as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include all the plugin assemblies, it can be one of the custom WF that you might have forgotten to include. Was facing the same issue, and including the plugin-assembly helped remove this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc1cu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).